# Live search results clickable using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am able to search and display the results that the user is typing on the keyup function. But now when the results show up inside my `<div>` tag, they are not clickable. Is there a way I can make them clickable and also allow the user to select multiple results from the live search results. This is what I tried so far.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id ="medication" name="medication" onkeyup="getsearch(this.value)"><br>
<div id="livesearch"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
function getsearch(val) {
  results = [];
  document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML = "";

  if (val.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border = "0px";
    return;
  }
  console.log(s);
  console.log("val", val);
  if (val.length > 2) {
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
      for (key in s[i]) {
        if (s[i][key].indexOf(val) != -1) {

          $("#livesearch").append(s[i][key]);
          $("#livesearch").append("<br/>");
          results.push(s[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(results);
};
```

Comment: Sure you can make anything clickable by assigning a click event handler to it.

Comment: @user9263373:- Can you kindly guide me a bit ?

Comment: Currently what you're doing is append your text with a `<br>` to your `#livesearch` div.  In order to assign a click handler to it, you'll have to wrap it in an html tag (`<li>`, `<span>` etc) and give it a class (i.e., `.appended`).  Then create a click handler `$(document).on("click",".appended",function() {...some code here...});`

Comment: Also I'm confused where your variable `s` is coming from? Unless I'm not seeing something, it isn't getting initialized or set anywhere in your `getsearch` function

Comment: Even more, you can directly insert a multiple select within your #livesearch div.

Comment: I don't know why this didn't occur to me earlier but you don't need to reinvent the wheel.  There are plugins already available with this functionality already coded in.  Personally I've used [**jQuery autocomplete**](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) and [**select2**](https://select2.org/).  There's also [**chosen.js**](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) which looks just as easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

There are some other thing I would do differently here, but as far as what you are looking to do this should work.

```
if(val.length>2) {
         for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
             for (key in s[i]) {
                 if (s[i][key].indexOf(val) != -1) {
                     var newDom = $('<div><\div>'); //create a DOM element to wrap each of the return  text in.

                     newDom.text(s[i][key]); 

                     $("#livesearch").append(newDom);

                     results.push(s[i]);
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

Then you can assign the click event to you dynamically created DOM this way.

```
$('#livesearch').on('click', 'div', myDoStuffFunc);

 function myDoStuffFunc(){
     // this is fired from the click event
 }
```